# How traffic routing happens in Kubernetes operator - Journey of Egress traffic

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-operator, kubernetes-networking

I am trying to understand about egress traffic controlling in [Kubernetes-Operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/). If I implement Kubernetes operator in my k3s setup, how the egress traffic flow happens in the operator?

I want to understand that what pathway/gateway and routing happens with egress traffic flow happens in the Kubernetes operator (journey of egress traffic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, egress traffic leaves your SDN from the Node hosting your Pod. The Node would NAT it, using its own IP on your underlay network.

Now, if by Egress you mean "anything that leaves my Pod" / regarding communications that stay within the SDN. Bearing in mind that:

- the SDN has two subnets (pod network, service network), and that your pod network is split into smaller subnets, statically allocated to your Kubernetes nodes:
- Services have (usually/when spec.clusterIP != None) their own fixed IP.
- for each Service in your cluster, you have an Endpoint object, that lists all Pods with matching labels, that are considered to be "Ready"

Connecting a Service, the Node firewall (usually ipvs or iptables, as configured per kube-proxy) would redirect your connection one of the addresses listed in the corresponding Endpoint object. At which point, your Node routing table takes over:

- if the target address is local (in the pod subnet that was allocated to your Node), then communication is direct.
- if the target address belong to a network allocated to another node in your cluster, then traffic would go through your SDN containers (calico, flannel, ovs, ...), reaching its destination.

Comment: @SYN-: Two que I have in your last two bullet points : 1. If the target address is local : so exmple can be another pod in same namespace or app running in another pod in same NS ? If yes, then according to you communication is direct ? what does direct mean here ?
2.  if the target address belong to a network allocated to another node : by another node you mean another pod ? here lets take exmple of google.com. If my target address is google.com then it will go via SDN, can it be through kubernetes operator instead of calico, flannel, cilium etc ?

Comment: @SYN-: Also In k3s setup default coredns pod is created with rancher image rancher/coredns-coredns:1.8.3 . So in my case egress traffic will be going through coredns if my target address is google.com? I mean where does coredns play a role in egress calls ?

Comment: When I say address is "local", I mean in terms of nodes / routing: if both source and target Pod are on the same Node, they have an IP within the same pod subnet, communications would not leave that Node. In regards to DNS resolution, client Pod may connect your cluster DNS server, which may in turn issue its own queries -- or serve clients with cached answers. Strictly speaking, your application Pod traffic does not leave the SDN. Though for sure CoreDNS would eventually connect either some internal (corporate LAN) or public resolver.